# Laravel Multilayered groupBy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Assume we have this record:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|   id  |   relation_id |   color       |   text        |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |       1       |   /* null */  |   text_001    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   2   |       1       |   /* null */  |   text_002    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   3   |       2       |   /* null */  |   text_003    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   4   |       2       |   /* null */  |   text_004    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   5   |       3       |   /* null */  |   text_005    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   6   |       3       |   /* null */  |   text_006    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   7   |       4       |       red     |   text_007    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   8   |       4       |       red     |   text_008    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   9   |       4       |       green   |   text_009    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   10  |       4       |       green   |   text_010    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   11  |       4       |       blue    |   text_011    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   12  |       4       |       blue    |   text_012    |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

While assuming we have this code in our `DummyController`:

```
// take note, groupBy() is using a relation here
public function index(Dummy $dummy)
{
    $dummyRecord = $dummy->with('anotherModel')->get()->sortBy('relation_id')->groupBy('anotherModel.column_name');
    return view('index')->with('dummyRecord', $dummyRecord);
}
```

And lastly, assuming we have `@foreach ($dummyRecord as $dummy_column_name => $dummy)` inside our `index.blade`, we could display the result as such:

```
// assume this is a div
---------------------
|   relation 1      |
---------------------
|       text_001    |
|       text_002    |
---------------------

// assume this is a div
---------------------
|   relation 2      |
---------------------
|       text_003    |
|       text_004    |
---------------------

// assume this is a div
---------------------
|   relation 3      |
---------------------
|       text_005    |
|       text_006    |
---------------------

// assume this is a div
---------------------
|   relation 4      |
---------------------
|       text_007    |
|       text_008    |
|       text_009    |
|       text_010    |
|       text_011    |
|       text_012    |
---------------------
```

But I want to display the `relation 4`'s record of `color` as a div inside a div, which makes the final output look like this inside the `index.blade` file:

```
// assume this is a div
---------------------
|   relation 1      |
---------------------
|       text_001    |
|       text_002    |
---------------------

// assume this is a div
---------------------
|   relation 2      |
---------------------
|       text_003    |
|       text_004    |
---------------------

// assume this is a div
---------------------
|   relation 3      |
---------------------
|       text_005    |
|       text_006    |
---------------------

// assume this is a div
---------------------------------------------
|   relation 4                              |
---------------------------------------------
|                                           |
|   // assume this is a div inside a div    |
|   -----------------                       |
|   |   red         |                       |
|   -----------------                       |
|   |   text_007    |                       |
|   |   text_008    |                       |
|   -----------------                       |
|                                           |
|   // assume this is a div inside a div    |
|   -----------------                       |
|   |   green       |                       |
|   -----------------                       |
|   |   text_009    |                       |
|   |   text_010    |                       |
|   -----------------                       |
|                                           |
|   // assume this is a div inside a div    |
|   -----------------                       |
|   |   blue        |                       |
|   -----------------                       |
|   |   text_011    |                       |
|   |   text_012    |                       |
|   -----------------                       |
|                                           |
---------------------------------------------
```

Should I use another `groupBy` to sort the record of colors, or is there another sorting code I could add inside the `index.blade` file?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provided the actual content of your blade file to see what you tried so far.

Comment: Did you know, that you can [group by multiple nested properties](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) like that: `$dummy->with('anotherModel')->get()->sortBy('relation_id')->groupBy(['anotherModel.column_name', 'anotherModel.anotherColumn_name']);`?

Comment: I see. The multilayered groupBy is now answered using the docs and your example. But how could I display the result in the blade using the foreach?

Comment: BTW, you can repost your previous comment as the answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer later when posted.

Comment: You need a nested `@foreach`. Just one sec and you'll get your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [group by multiple nested properties](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) like that:

```
$dummy
    ->with('anotherModel')
    ->get()
    ->sortBy('relation_id')
    ->groupBy(['anotherModel.column_name', 'anotherModel.anotherColumn_name']);
```

And loop over it in your blade like that:

```
@foreach(/* ... */)
    <div>
        relation {{ $i }}
        @foreach(/* ... */)
            <div>
                {{ $color }}
                @foreach(/* ... */)
                   {{ $text}}
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I wasn't sure what you'd loop over in your `@foreach()` statements but I thought, you'd figure that out.

Comment: Yeah that's now easy for me to figure out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use collection [map()][1] to solve the purpose.

```php
$dummy->with('anotherModel')
    ->get()
    ->sortBy('relation_id')
    ->groupBy('relation_id', true)
    ->map(function($q){
        // group by color
        return collect($q)->groupBy('color', true);
    })
    ->all();


  [1]: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map
```